# Jekyll includes escapes closing tags?

Tags: html, include, escaping, jekyll

So I have a site with the following basic structure:

```
<body>
  <section>
    <p>Text of Section 1</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Text of Section 2</p>
  </section>
...
</body>
```

I want to generate the entire site from a markdown file using jekyll, but since markdown doesn't know anything like sections my idea was to use markdown for the normal text and then include the missing html from another file, like this:

```
---
layout: default.html
---

Text of Section 1.

{% include sectionbreak.html %}

Text of Section 2.
```

For this, `sectionbreak.html` must contain something like

```
</section>
<section>
```

However, `jekyll` appears to automatically escape any closing html tags at the start of an include file, and the result is a website more like this, stacking more and more sections inside each other:

```
<body>
  <section>
    <p>Text of Section 1</p>
  <p>&lt;/section&gt;</p>
  <section>
    <p>Text of Section 2</p>
 ...
</body>
```

Does anyone have an idea for how to disable this behaviour, or what do do instead to generate the website?

Answer (score 1):

Is this an every page kind of thing? Or only a specialty front page?  I don't see why you'd want to create regular everyday posts like this, but I've done this for my front page, where I have something like this:

```
|-...
|- _landing
 |- intro.md
 |- blog.md
 |- projects.md
|- index.html
```

Within my `index.hml` which is my home page, I pull in all the `_landing` collection sorted by `frontmatter.index`.  It'll let you reorder and add sections to your main page, where `landing/blog.md` contains only the latest 5-10 entries and a link to `pages/archive.html` which contains the full paginated list of posts.

Again, I wouldn't suggest this for every page on your site, but it works well for the specialty pages of which I have a limited number.  Things like:

- index/landing page with multiple summary sections linking to full pages
- contact page with multiple contact sections

**Edit**

How about this for a hail mary, I have zero idea if it would work or not without going through the jekyll source, but:

```
{% assign sections = page.content | split:"<!-- SPLIT -->" %}
{% for section in sections %}
<section>
  {{ section }}
</section>
<banner>
</banner>
{% endfor %}
```

Quick google shows that this might not be as crazy as I thought: https://gist.github.com/Phlow/04f635e4d1fc928b1157

Comment: it's an every page kind of thing — the idea is to put banners with quotes between the sections, which go across the whole page and don't work when they are inside a section. I had something like what you describe with multiple files already, but wanted to combine them into one as otherwise it starts being a hassle with all the smaller files (also maybe important note: I'm not writing a blog, just multiple sites linked to each other).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is not with Jekyll, but with Markdown. As far as I can tell, there is no way to get [Jekyll-flavored Markdown](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/) to interpret a dangling/lone `</closing tag>` correctly. It will be interpreted as plain text and wrapped in a `<p>` paragraph.

At first I came up with something like what the other answer showed:

**`/_layouts/default.html`**

```
{%- assign content = content | replace: "<!-- section break -->", "</section><section>" -%}

<section>
  {{ content }}
</section>
```

---

But eventually I needed to attach parameters to the section as well. Here's the terribly hacky way I accomplished that.

**`/_includes/section.html`**

```
<!-- $uncomment </section> $uncomment -->
<!-- $uncomment <section style="background-color: {{ include.background }}"> $uncomment -->
```

**`/_layouts/default.html`**

```
{% assign content = content | replace:"<!-- $uncomment ","" %}
{% assign content = content | replace:" $uncomment -->","" %}
```

**`index.md`**

```markdown
blah blah blah plain section

{% include section.html %}

blah blah blah plain section

{% include section.html background="#ff0000" %}

blah blah blah section with red background color
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! For anyone else hitting this, it looks like kramdown has an escape hatch which produces a simpler fix: if you wrap the include in `{::nomarkdown}` and `{:/nomarkdown}` it will not try to be clever and leave your HTML alone without `replace` trickery.

Comment: @BenKraft the {::nomarkdown} and {:/nomarkdown}should absolutely be an answer